# E_ERROR : type 1

Tags: php, memory

I always receive error as I run following code ,it work perfectly fine if I assign heavyDeciCount ($x,$y) value manualy.any idea ,thanks

E_ERROR : type 1 -- Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) -- at line 51

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test Phase 1</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
     <form action="" method="get">  

   <input type="text" name="x" />
   <input type="text" name="y" />
   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Calculate" />


  </form>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>


<?php

$mainArray = array();
function heavyDeciCount ($x,$y)
{
 for($i=$x;$i<=$y;$i++)
 {
  $number = $i;
  $numLength = strlen((string)$i);
  $digit = 0;
  for($j=0;$j<$numLength;$j++)
  {
   
   $digit = $digit + ($number % 10);
   $number = (int)$number / 10;
  }


 $avg = 0.00;
 $avg = round($digit/$numLength,2);
 if($avg>7)
 {
 $isHeavy = "Yes";
 }
 else
 {
 $isHeavy = "No";
 }
 global $mainArray;
 $mainArray[] = array($i,$avg,$isHeavy);
 }
}
}

heavyDeciCount (9272,9295);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Number</th><th>Average</th><th>Is Heavt</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($mainArray as $value1)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 foreach($value1 as $value)
 {
  echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";  
 }
 echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: if(isset($_GET['x']) && isset($_GET['y']))
 {
 $x=$_GET['x'];$y=$_GET['y'];
 HeavyDesiCount($x,$y);

Comment: you got probably an infinite loop there